# View procedure in multiple line in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer Version 4.1.2.20.

I expand the procedures folder, find the procedure I need to edit, and I right-click->Edit.

The procedure appears as one entire line, even though the procedure is multiple lines long.

Is there a view option to see the procedure with block structure with multiple lines?

Comment: Are you certain that the procedure actually has embedded line breaks?  If you query `[dba_|all_|user_]source`, are there multiple lines of text?  My first guess is that whatever created the procedure didn't embed line breaks.

Comment: @JustinCave I'll check tomorrow and update.